# Cloud-based time tracking service

Tags: web-apps, time-management, hosted

I'm looking for a cloud-based time tracking service for a 20 person company which allows employees to be logged in throughout the day and choose a work category from a drop down menu, choose the client ID number, enter the amount of time they spent working on a task for that client ID and briefly describe the task.

Anyone have suggestions and could you include why you suggest it?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for cloud-based time tracking: [**Toggl**](https://www.toggl.com/)

Also [for teams](https://www.toggl.com/tour/team).

Why I suggest it: two of my colleagues use the individual version for a few years already and I checked your teamwork needs against the specs on their site and as far as I can judge they match.